# Could not find a declaration file for module 'gulp'. 'c:/project/node_modules/gulp/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

I do not know what's wrong.

*gulpfile.js >> gulp and gulp-util and run-sequence error

**consle error message**
Could not find a declaration file for module 'gulp'. 'c:/project/node_modules/gulp/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as util from 'gulp-util';
import * as runSequence from 'run-sequence';
```

Comment: Have you installed the typings for gulp? `npm install --save-dev @types/gulp`?

Comment: yes, installed the typings for gulp
     `npm install gulp-typescript` and      
     `npm install --save-dev @types/gulp`

Comment: try to install global npm install -D @types/gulp

    import * as gulp from 'gulp';
    import * as util from 'gulp-util';
    import * as runSequence from 'run-sequence'; 


like this

    const gulp = require('gulp');
    const util = require('util');
    const runSequence =require('runSequence')